# Moving an Element with animation outside it's Panel

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, storyboard, mvvm-light

So what i'am trying to do is: move a button with storyboard animation from inside a Uniformgrid to a sibling which is a Listbox. As you can see from the image the below, the button does indeed move toward the Listbox (green rectangle), but once it goes outside the bounds of the ItemControls it disappears. I try to follow the mvvm pattern as best as i can(I use Mvvm light toolkit). So i try to keep most UI in the XAML.

So what I'am wondering is, what is the best solution to this?

- I have tried to make the itemscontrol fully overlap the listbox and decrease the size of the uniformgrid. This worked, but i have some buttons beside the Listbox that stopped working because they would be below the itemscontrol. So the button doesnt mind going out of the UniformGrids bounds for some reason.
- Would the best solution be to create a copy of the button, then move it? How would i go about doing something like that?

[image]

The XAML file. I have simplified it. (Sorry that it's still large)

```
<Canvas x:Name="Canvas">

<Grid x:Name="SymbolGrid"  Background="Transparent" Height="{Binding ElementName=Canvas, Path=ActualHeight}"
          Width="{Binding ElementName=Canvas, Path=ActualWidth}">


    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition ></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition ></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition ></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition ></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition ></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="180" ></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>



<!-- The listbox that i want the Button to move over -->
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Output}"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" >
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Path=Image}" Height="30"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="20" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>



    <ScrollViewer x:Name="TheScrollViewer" Grid.Row="0"  Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="7"
                          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"  >
        <ItemsControl   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding PageList}" >

            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>

                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollViewer}}" 
                          Width="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollViewer}}"  >
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <UniformGrid   Rows="4"  Columns="7" >
                                </UniformGrid>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
            <!-- The Button I want to move over the listbox -->
                                <Button  Width="200">

                                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                        <Image Source="{Binding Path=Image}" Height="100"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="20" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                    <Button.RenderTransform>
                                        <TranslateTransform></TranslateTransform>
                                    </Button.RenderTransform>
                                    <Button.Triggers>
                                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                                            <BeginStoryboard>

                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation  Duration="0:0:3" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.Y)"  

                            >
                                                        <DoubleAnimation.To>
                                                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource VerticalDistanceConverter}" >
                                                                <!-- Some converting done to get the relative Y position -->
                                                            </MultiBinding>
                                                        </DoubleAnimation.To>
                                                    </DoubleAnimation>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation   Duration="0:0:3" From="0"  Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)"  >
                                                        <DoubleAnimation.To>
                                                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource HorizontalDistanceConverter}" >
                                                                <!-- Some converting done to get the relative X position -->
                                                        </DoubleAnimation.To>
                                                    </DoubleAnimation>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                        </EventTrigger>
                                    </Button.Triggers>

                                </Button>


                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </DataTemplate>

            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>

</Grid>
```

I'll be grateful for any help :) thanks.

Comment: Is it possible for you to set the parent adorner of the ItemsControl to the parent Grid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would the best solution be to create a copy of the button, then move it?

No, don't relocate the button, have it move by adjusting the margins until it *appears* over the target location.

---

### Alternate Suggestion

Start the button out in the target location as hidden, followed by moving it over the grid, then make it visible?

Comment: Thanks for trying, but this did'nt do the job. By using Margin as TargetProperty, the buttons stops at the uniformgrid edges. :)

Comment: @Moddaman What if you reversed the cycle, start the button out in the target location as hidden, but actually move it over the grid, then make it visible? Once visible then clicked, reverse the process. ???

Comment: I found a solution, a little hacky, but it worked. So I never got to try this one out. Thanks for the help

Comment: Well, I actually ended doing it the way @OmegaMan explained in the second comment . Didn't need to hide the it either, because it was rendered when i hit the button in the grid. What I did was reverse the cycle and instead of setting the Doubleanimation.To position which I originally did to the button in the grid. I instead animated the button in the Listbox when it was loaded, and set the Doubleanimation.From to be the postion of the button pressed in the grid. thx

Comment: @Moddaman Your other solution was good I will +1 it. Thanks for letting us know.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I found the answer to my own question. This is probably not the best solution, but it worked for me and since it's only a prototype I can live with it.

As I said in my question:

- I have tried to make the itemscontrol fully overlap the listbox and decrease the size of the uniformgrid. This worked, but i have some buttons beside the Listbox that stopped working because they would be below the itemscontrol. So the button doesnt mind going out of the UniformGrids bounds for some reason.

The problem with this was that the buttons didn't work because it would be below (zindex wise) the itemscontrol which were expaned above both rows. The solution to making the buttons work again was something as logical as to move the buttons under the itemsource in the xaml file.

This is the "original":

```
    <Button Grid.row="0" Grid.column="0" .... /> //Button that did'nt work
    <ListBox Grid.row="0" Grid.column="1" Grid.columnspan="3"> .... </ListBox> //Target
    <Button Grid.row="0" Grid.column="4" .... /> //Button that did'nt work


    <ItemsControl Grid.row="0" Grid.rowspan="2" Grid.columnspan="5" > //Source.( You can see the rowspan of 2.)
        ....
        </ItemsControl>
```

The solution:

```
    <ListBox Grid.row="0" Grid.column="1" Grid.columnspan="3"> .... </ListBox> //Target

    <ItemsControl Grid.row="0" Grid.rowspan="2" Grid.columnspan="5" > //Source.( You can see the rowspan of 2.)
        ....
        </ItemsControl>

    <Button Grid.row="0" Grid.column="0" .... /> 
    <Button Grid.row="0" Grid.column="4" .... />
```

This works because now the button has a higher Zindex than the itemsource. Making it possible to interact with them.

But as I said: This is not a good solution, so if anyone knows of a good way to do this, please speak. Because I'am very curious.

Thanks for the help!